# RSS Feed error: "cURL error 22: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"

Tags: php, rss, curl

I'm trying to load the following RSS feed in a Joomla! Feeds module:

https://community.joomla.org/events/view,rss.xml

However, I get the following error:

> cURL error 22: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden

I don't understand because I can successfully visit the feed, so I don't expect to see a 403 error.  I also don't expect an RSS feed to be forbidden or else that defeats the point.

Does anyone know what else this error could mean?

Comment: Show us exactly how you are fetching it.  My Google searchings indicate that there may be interference due to proxy or a corporate network.  We may need to know more about your environment.

Comment: Hmm, now that's an interesting thought, I'll try it on a different website.

Comment: Please answer the question you are right.

Comment: How do I troubleshoot it?  I can't move the module to a new server, so I'll need to fix the environment somehow.  What should I be Googling.

Comment: Truth is, I don't know what I'm talking about.  I've never used that module, never experienced the issue, don't know how to diagnose or fix the environment.  I Googled your error code and drifted from SE site to SE site gathering the gist of the advice.  I am just suggesting ways to continue researching; I have no business posting an answer on this one.  Good luck.  Perhaps you or another volunteer will be able to run with my hint.

Comment: Thanks, I actually was using a 3rd party module and switching to core fixed this.  So there we have it.

Comment: Well then, let's see this page legitimately resolved and in an educational manner.  Please post an answer with your insights and the steps you took to alleviate your troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused by the **AutoTweet NG Light RSS** module.

As I could see the RSS feed in my browser I was reasonably sure the **403 forbidden** error was a red herring.

I tested this by trying Joomla! Core **Mod_feed (feed display)**, this worked.  I can only assume some sort of server configuration error due to **cURL** but I do not control the server so this is hard for me to test.